# step out (shift F11) from tedious deep levels call stacks

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

Hi I am quite tired of pressing shift + F11 for stepping out from a deep/long call stack level.
I cannot detach and attach debugger; if I dettach the debugger, I will miss the next breakpoint.

is there any way to step out from current breakpoint (current call stack) all the way to the call stack breakpoint as shown in attachment?

Thank you

Comment: Double-click the function you want to resume debugging in and set a breakpoint on the statement after the call.  Press F5.  This is of course best avoided by using step-over more judiciously.

Comment: thanks Hans, shame on me :)  change your comment to answer and I'll accept yours.